# To prove that $G$ is the group the condition is not necessary $\forall a,b, c \in G(ba=ca\to b=c)$.?

Tags: group-theory

$1.$ Let $G$ be a finite semigroup such that

$\forall a,b, c \in G(ab=ac\to b=c)$.

Then $G$ is Group. ?

I know the following result : If $G$ be a finite semigroup such that

$\forall a,b, c \in G(ab=ac\to b=c)$ and $\forall a,b, c \in G(ba=ca\to b=c)$

Then $G$ is Group.

To prove that $G$ is the group the condition is not necessary $\forall a,b, c \in G(ba=ca\to b=c)$. ?

There exists an contraexample for $1.$

Comment: Is the "last" operation $ab=b$ for all $a,b$ a semigroup operation?

Comment: They are not a *finite* semigroup @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Hello Thomas, the non-negative are not finite

Comment: Whoops, yes, sorry, I thought you were saying you knew the finite case and were considering the infinite case. Misread.

Comment: Should the title say "... is not *sufficient*"? I may just be confused, but if it's not *necessary*, then you should be able to find some groups that don't have left cancellation. But if it's not *sufficient*, then you'll find semigroups with left cancellation that aren't groups (i.e., you can't weaken the result you know that requires both).

Answer (score 4):

Let $S$ be any finite set, and define $a\star b = b$ for all $a,b\in S$. Show this is a semigroup, and has your property. Show it is not a group if $|S|>1$.

If a finite semigroup $S$ has the above property *plus* the property that if $a\neq b$ then there is a $c$ so that $ac\neq bc$, then you can prove it is a group. (This second condition is true, for example, when $S$ has a right-identity, or if cancellation works the other way as well: $ba=ca\implies b=c$.)

This is because the map $\phi_a:b\mapsto a\cdot b$ is always a permutation of $S$ if $S$ is finite and has your condition, and this second condition says that $a\to\phi_a$ is one-to-one - if $\phi_a=\phi_b$ then $a=b$. We can show this is a homomorphism of $S$ to $\Sigma(S)$, the group of permutations of $S$, it is $1-1$, and therefore makes the $S$ isomorphic to the image of $S$, which is easily seen to be a subgroup of $\Sigma(S)$.

In my example with $a\star b=b$ for all elements, the map $S\to \Sigma(S)$ is not one-to-one. Every element of $S$ is sent to the identity permutation.